# Math notation, conditional sum

Tags: notation, vectors

I calculate an index; the length of a vector given a conditional statement (mean of the vector) in relation to the unconditional length of the vector. My question is how does one write this in proper math notation?

I've thought that something like this may be close to appropriate, but really this is just a wild guess. I can't seem to find some good guidance for such a specific question.

\begin{eqnarray}
 W = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i}\vert X_{i} < \bar{X}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i}}
\end{eqnarray}\

Is anyone comfortable guiding me with this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) of a random variable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is standard notation for your calculation. What you wrote is clear enough. I suggest you invent a notation for it, define it once at the start of your document, along with an example, and then use it. Perhaps

> $$ W(X, \bar X) = \ldots $$ is the sum of the entries in vector $X$
> less than  $\bar X$ divided by the sum of the entries in $X$. For
> example ...

Note: This is not an "index". I think you should call this "weight", or "relative weight" not "length". Both "index" and "length" have other meanings that your reader will confuse with yours.

Comment: Yeah... ok, seems like a good suggestion. Thank you.